# How to set editText object based on item clicked from listView

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, onclicklistener

I am trying to figure out how to set the text in my `editText` object based on an item I have saved in my `listView`. I am in the process of building a complex dice roller for DnD. This takes the users input and calculates the value, the user can also save the rolls for a later use. How do it get it populate the `editText` object for the user to re roll their dice? Here is the code that I use to save to `listView`:

```
public void saveToList(){
        String getInput = et_roll1.getText().toString();

        if (addArray.contains(getInput)){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item Already Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (getInput == null || getInput.trim().equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Input Field is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            addArray.add(getInput);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addArray);
            lv_rolls.setAdapter(adapter);
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_roll1)).setText(" "); //reset editText to blank
        }
```

Here is the code for my `onClickListener`:

```
lv_rolls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                resetValue();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lv_rolls.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       tv_roll1_result.setText(" ");
       et_roll1.setText(String.valueOf(lv_rolls.getItemAtPosition(position)));


    }
});
```